# No matching function for call to 'strcmp' xcode

Tags: c++, string, xcode, class, strcmp

Hey i have this problem with my program in xcode - he doesn't recognize strcmp function from string library.
I add #include  and #include  but it still doesn't work...
(it's a string class)
if you can help me with this, it would be great (i'm a begginer in c++)
thank u

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "MyString.h"
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

bool MyString::operator!=(MyString other){
    if(strcmp(str, other)==0) //error here
        return true;
    return false;
}

bool MyString::operator<=(MyString other){
    if(strcmp(str, other)==0 or strcmp(str, other)==-1) //error here
        return true;
    return false;
}

bool MyString::operator>=(MyString other){
    if(strcmp(str, other)==0 or strcmp(str, other)==1) //error here
        return true;
    return false;
}

bool MyString::operator<(MyString other){
    if(strcmp(str, other)==-1) //error here
        return true;
    return false;
}

bool MyString::operator>(MyString other){
    if(strcmp(str, other)==1) //error here
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: In `if(strcmp(str, other)==1) //error here` don't you want  `other.str` instead of `other` which is an object of your MyString

Comment: Also you should pass by reference instead of by value. I expect you did not handle the rule of 3 / 5 / 0 so passing by value can not only be unoptimal but cause undefined behavior.

Comment: ***No matching function for call to 'strcmp' xcode*** The full error message should have told you more than this which should have hinted that its not a header problem. Error messages can be difficult to read at first but it will help you in the long run if you try to understand what the error message tells you.

Comment: `strcmp()` operates on `char*` arguments.  What is the type of `str`?  `other` is a `MyString` -- can that class be implicitly converted to `char*`?

Comment: Also, you don't want to include `<stdio.h>` and `<string.h>'; you want `<cstdio>` and <`cstring`>.  stdio.h and string.h have been deprecated in C++ since 1998.

Comment: ok thank u everyone i think i found my error its because other is a MyString (like you said @user3553031) so i add .getString() function and its work!

Comment: `if(strcmp(str, other)==1)` probably should be `if(strcmp(str, other.str)==1)`